# Not getting the result of stored procedure through Jasper

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jasper-reports

I have a oracle stored procedure and when I execute it in sql developer I get for example 12 rows as a result. Then I make a Jasper report which calls the same procedure and I schedule report to be sent via mail in Jaspersoft. What I get is an empty report. Does anyone know what colud be the problem? 
Also it seems that option Dont send empty reports doesn't work well at least in my case. When I schedule report in Jaspersoft, I check this option but I still get empty reports via mail. Has anyone had simular problem?

Comment: Maybe you have data you added in the same SQL Developer session which you haven't committed?

Comment: First, make sure the report runs standalone without a problem. Then, to make sure it runs ok, set `All sections no detail` in `No data` to investigate further. If all works out, the server might be misconfigured.

Comment: Thank you both, it seems Alex guessed what the problem was. Problem with receiving empty reports still remains :(

Comment: I found out what the problem was with sending empty reports. In No data NULL should be set up.